# The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e4b in the message file for OraOLEDB

Tags: excel, oracle, oraoledb

What could mean the following message? The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e4b in the message file for OraOLEDB.

Answer (score 1):

This error message can be very confusing and the solution can be surprisingly primitive.
In my case: Oracle stored procedure sends recordset to MS Excel via "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source= ...etc" .
The problem was many decimal numbers in the Oracle data column sent to Excel 2010. When I used Oracle SQL query ROUND(grosssales_eur,2) AS grosssales_eur, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a list of OleDB error codes under [this link](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6420_tc3_database_server/108091659.html&id=). Your error code corresponds to "The specified accessor was not a parameter accessor".

These error message strings corresponding to certain error codes are normally kept in "message files". It seems that the message file for OraOLEDB does not contain a string for your error code, and just gives you the error code instead.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciated. The crucial for me was the root cause, that number of decimal numbers can cause such error in data transfer. This needs some intuition and I wanted to help other victims and saved their time of the investigation. Miroslav

Comment: Awesome. The description for 0x80040E21 is "Error". Thanks Oracle developers!

Answer (score 0):

OK I have recently started getting this message again while refactoring a bunch of sql to be parameterized instead of interpolated string (**do not judge**) in my application, in the form:
**The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e0c in the message file for OraOLEDB**.

In my case  for **this particular code**,  the problem was due to either **OleDbParameter** objects that were missing, added to the collection for the command in the wrong order, or defined but not used in the **OleDbCommand**.  So check those to make sure the types are right, correct position as they are completely positional despite naming, and used when defined.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error originated because a data type changed in the data source but I did not update it in the dimension. Adjusting that fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

The system cannot find message text for message number 0x80040e0c in the message file for OraOLEDB, such error message indicates single or multiple errors like integrity constraint including null inserting into not null columns, unique constraint. I have fixed the error by redirecting such bad/incorrect records before inserting them into the destination table. You can try if you are getting such error message. Thanks!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is a different message number from the question, so likely has a different cause.